# Синхронные HTTP-запросы с RxJava и Retrofit

Tags: android, rxjava

Всем привет!

**Дано:**

`API` от смс-сервиса, запрос выглядит вот так(использую `Retrofit2`):

```
 @POST("testsend/?")
    Observable<SmsStatus> sendSMS(
            @Field("user") String user,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("to") String to,
            @Field("text") String text,
            @Field("from") String from,
            @Field("answer")String answer
    );
```

*Observable:*

```
  ApiSms service = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiSms.class);
        Observable<SmsStatus> observSmsStatus = service.sendSMS(
                "****************"//тут логин
                ,"****************"// тут API-key
                ,"************"//тут номер
                ,"test"
                ,"news"
                ,"json"//формат ответа
        );

        observSmsStatus
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SmsStatus>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        Log.e("It's not ok", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SmsStatus smsStatus) {
                        Log.e("It's ok",smsStatus.result);
                    }
                });
```

Это работает. Смс отправляется.

**Вопрос:**

Мне нужно сделать 5 асинхронных `HTTP`-запросов (каждый из них отправляет смс-сообщение и принимает `JSON`). Т.е., чтобы одновременно стартовало 5 запросов в сеть, а ответы имели доступ к `UI`-потоку.

Как это можно реализовать с применением `RxJava`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам, таки, надо запустить 5 **А**синхронных запросов

```
public interface RestApi {
    String URL = "http://server/";
    RestApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()
            .create(RestApi.class);

    @POST("testsend/?")
    Observable<SmsStatus> sendSMS(
            @Field("user") String user,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("to") String to,
            @Field("text") String text,
            @Field("from") String from,
            @Field("answer")String answer
    );
}

public class MainClass{
    public void makeRequests(){
        request(...params1....);
        request(...params2....);
        request(...params3....);
        request(...params4....);
        request(...params5....);
    }

    private void request(...params...) {
        RestApi.api.sendSMS(....params....)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...implementation...);        
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас попробую